# Array of strings condenced based on character limit for pages acting weirdly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to convert an array of individual actions(strings) into an array of less strings that are composed of multiple actions for pages. But I want the pages to not exceed a certain character limit, but once it gets towards the end, it takes too many items and pushes them to the end for seemingly no reason.

Code is here and on [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/ojorasonud.js)

```
module.exports = {
    stringsToPages: (strings) =>{
        // below is just a display of what is passed - not actually in my code.
        var strings = ["1 Received a ban","2 Had a ban removed","3 Received a ban","4 Had a ban removed","5 Received a ban","6 Had a ban removed","7 Received a ban","8 Had a ban removed","9 Received a ban","10 Had a ban removed","11 Received a ban","12 Had a ban removed","13 Received a ban"]

        let pages = []; // Initate pages array to return
        var limit = 50; // Character limit

        let it = 0; // Run iteration
        let tot = 0; // Total string length
        let setlen = 0; // Length of the set to cut into a new page.
        var clone = strings.slice(0); // Clone array

        strings.forEach(i => {
            it++;

            let len = tot+i.length+2; // Getting Size & adding two for "\n"
            if(len >= limit){ 
                pages.push(clone.splice(0,setlen).join(`\n`));
                tot = 0;
                setlen = 0;
            } else {
                tot = tot+i.length;
                setlen++;
            }

            // If on last iteration, check and see if the clone array has more items, if so join and push them.
            if(it === strings.length){
                if(clone.length > 0){
                    pages.push(clone.join(`\n`));
                }
            }   
        }); 


        return pages; // below is what is returned - not actually in my code.
        var result = ["1 Received a ban\n2 Had a ban removed","3 Received a ban\n4 Had a ban removed","5 Received a ban\n6 Had a ban removed","7 Received a ban\n8 Had a ban removed","9 Received a ban\n10 Had a ban removed\n11 Received a ban\n12 Had a ban removed\n13 Received a ban"]
    }
}
```

The final result has split 13 items into 5 pages with pages 1-4 providing 2 items, and page 5 with 5 items. When it should be 7 pages with 1-6 having 2 items and 6 having 1. Well rather I need it to, not it should, because its obviously not.

Comment: A guess would be that you async operations results with a greater amount of  (strings) therefore the unexpected output...

Comment: @eugensunic I just removed the async/await on my side and it changed nothing. I guess I didn't need it in the first place, thought I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, does this work for you?

```js
const stringsToPages = (strings) => {
  // below is just a display of what is passed - not actually in my code.
  var strings = ["1 Received a ban", "2 Had a ban removed", "3 Received a ban", "4 Had a ban removed", "5 Received a ban", "6 Had a ban removed", "7 Received a ban", "8 Had a ban removed", "9 Received a ban", "10 Had a ban removed", "11 Received a ban", "12 Had a ban removed", "13 Received a ban"]

  let pages = ['']; // Initate pages array to return
  let currPage = 0;
  var limit = 50; // Character limit
  var clone = strings.slice(0); // Clone array

  clone.forEach(i => {
    let curPageLen = (pages[currPage] + i).length + 2;
    if (curPageLen >= limit) {
      pages[++currPage] = '';
    }
    pages[currPage] = `${pages[currPage]}\n${i}`;
  });


  return pages; // below is what is returned - not actually in my code.
}

let pages = stringsToPages();
console.log(pages);
pages.forEach(p => console.log(p.length));
```

Comment: This is working as I needed it to, thank you very much.